# Prove/disprove radius about radius of convergnce

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following statement -

The Taylor series of $\frac{x}{x+2}$ around $X = 1$ has a radius of convergence of $R = 4$.

Is it right to say that this statement is **false** because a function is well-defined for all $x$ inside it's radius of convergence , but this function is not defined for $x = -2$?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Put

$$\frac x{x+2}=\frac x{3+(x-1)}=\frac x3\frac1{1+\frac{x-1}3}=\frac x3\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(x-1)^k}{3^k}$$

and the above is valid whenever

$$\left|\frac{x-1}3\right|<1\iff |x-1|<3$$

And **yes** about your question: good work

Comment: Thanks, I did it also in your way , but just want ti verify the a function is well defined in the radius interval and also derivate for infinite times?

Comment: @G That's always true: a function defined by a power series is *always* differentiable and integrable **termwise** within the *open* convergence interval.

Comment: Forget my last comment.